# C# culture: hours and minutes in different language

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

Is it possible to get hour/hours minute/minutes texts in different language in .net? Does the culture info contains this kind of information? or I need to create an own library with translations..

Goal is to  write it like

```
en: 2 hours 45 minutes
es: 2 horas 45 minutos

en: 1 hour 1 minute
es: 1 hora 1 minuto
```

Comment: C# doesn't have a built-in way to translate that. You'd either need to [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485027/timespan-to-localized-string-in-c-sharp) or use a third party library like Humanizer.

Comment: @gunr2171 You should probably post that as an answer, because it is THE answer to the question. :)

Comment: I'd rather mark as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

While some aspects of a `DateTime` format may be configured with a CultureInfo (e.g. A.M., P.M. designators), the terms "minutes" and "hours" are not provided by any built-in `DateTime` method output (i.e. `ToString`). You would have to add a library or do it yourself.
See [here for more about `DateTimeFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat?view=net-5.0) with cultures, and see [here for more about culture info in general](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0).